# export data in bag file using rqt_bag

Tags: ros, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to extract sensor and images data that saved in a bag file and save them into csv and image (png?) respectively.
For old rxbag, it can be easily done by following:
Select the range of the data we want,
Plot the sensor data, right click the plot and save into csv.
Show the image and there is a button to save the images.

However, I cannot find those option in the rqt_bag.

Thanks very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198372/export-data-in-bag-file-using-rqt_bag/) by [linshenzhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/20946/linshenzhen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe either of these features have been implemented in rqt_bag yet. Sorry.

You can file a feature request here: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues

If you feel these features are very important, consider implementing them yourself and opening a pull request.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0